# jQuery slideToggle function run only on relevant element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to run jQuery `slideToggle` function only on concrete `menu` element that placed near to any clicked `menu-title` element.

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <h4 class="menu-title">Menu 1</h4>
    <ul class="menu>
        <li class="menu-item">
           <a class="nav-link" href="#">1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
           <a class="nav-link" href="#">2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
           <a class="nav-link" href="#">3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
 <div class="dropdown">
    <h4 class="menu-title">Menu 2</h4>
    <ul class="menu>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<style>
.dropdown-menu{
   display: none;
}
</style>

$('.menu-title').click(function(){
  $('.menu').slideToggle();
});
```

The issue is when click on one of the title it's working on all `ul` elements together.

Can you please guide me how to make it work on each ul separate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use siblings function of **jQuery**

`$(this).siblings('.menu').slideToggle();`

Answer (score 5):

use siblings method

`$(this).siblings('.menu').slideToggle();`

note: your html has error, you forgot to close menu class in html -it should be `class="menu"`-, also your is css wrong, it should be `.dropdown .menu`  not `.dropdown-menu`.

code: https://codepen.io/peker-ercan/pen/MPvgYp

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.menu-title').click(function(){
  $('.menu').slideToggle();
});
$('.menu').mouseover(function(){
  $('.menu-item').slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('.menu-title').click(function(){
       $(this).siblings('.menu').slideToggle();
    })
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a lot more useful if you provided an explanation as to *how* it answers it.